# inherit constructors from vector

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, using-directives

In Stroustrup, C++ Programming Language 4th Edition, he wrote the on page 79 the following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <allocators>
using std::vector;
using namespace std;
template<class T>
class Vector : vector<T> 
{
private:
    T elem[50];
    int size;
public:
    ***using vector<T>::vector; // inherit constructors***
    T& operator[](size_type i) { check(i); return this−>elem(i); }
    const T& operator=(size_type i) const {
        check(i); 
        return this−>elem(i);
    }
    void check(size_type i) { if (this−>size()<i) throw Bad_index(i); }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Vector <int> V{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the program, I receive the following errors:

> Error 3   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from
>   'initializer-list' to 'Vector'   c:\computer programming\c++
>   programming
>   language\code\ch3\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3.cpp 28  1   ConsoleApplication3
>
> Error 1   error C2886: 'vector>' : symbol cannot
>   be used in a member using-declaration c:\computer programming\c++
>   programming
>   language\code\ch3\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3.cpp 17  1   ConsoleApplication3
>
> Error 2   error C2886: 'vector>' : symbol cannot
>   be used in a member using-declaration c:\computer programming\c++
>   programming
>   language\code\ch3\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3.cpp 17  1   ConsoleApplication3
>     4   IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "Vector::Vector [with
>   T=int]" matches the argument list
>               argument types are: (int, int, int, int)  c:\Computer Programming\C++ Programming
>   Language\Code\Ch3\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3.cpp 28  16  ConsoleApplication3

My question involves mostly Error 2 error C2886: which refers to the using directive.  Visual Basic defines the error as follow:

> *'class::identifier' : symbol cannot be used in a member using-declaration 
>   A using declaration uses a symbol, such as a namespace name. A using declaration is for declaring base class members.*

Stroustrup apparently uses it but I have failed to duplicate his method.  Is there a header I am missing or what?  Could someone explain my error? thank you jmg.

Comment: I always heard inheriting from std containers was a bad idea. Very suprised to see Stroustrup doing it. Also I don't see the point of it, if you are going to declare your own storage. Why inherit from vector?

Comment: @NeilKirk People usually mean public inheritance when they say that, and they usually assume derived objects are going to get deleted from a poiter to vector. I don' think it is such a bad idea in this case.

Comment: It works well with [clang](http://rextester.com/PJMSL38069) and [gcc](http://rextester.com/BUEPH92181), but not [vc](http://rextester.com/LSJJU71919).

Comment: [This MCVE](http://ideone.com/SE1nzi) works. It is most likely your compiler not supporting C++11.

Comment: In my Straustrup book this is on page 97, not 79 and its not the same code you have here. You are inheriting from `std::vector` as well as implementing your own internal array which seems redundant.

Comment: @Galik It seems we have the same book :)